# How to change internal preview PDF source file location TexStudio

Tags: pdftex, texstudio

I have just started using TexStudio today and am very new to using LaTex to write documents.

After successful compilation of my .tex file, the resultant PDF file is saved within the same directory of my .tex file.

However, I am unable to get a preview of the PDF file within the internal preview window as for some reason TexStudio looks through another directory to grab the PDF file for viewing.

I get this error at the bottom of the screen

```
Failed to find file "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Temp\texstudio_a11452.pdf"; perhaps it has been deleted.
```

How do I change the location of where the internal preview searches for the PDF file? Is it possible to make it search through the directory that the .tex file is in?

My command settings:

[image]

My build settings:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue by enabling `Show Advanced Options` within the build settings.

There I edited the `Additional Search Paths` under `Build Options` to include `output` under PDF and everything works fine now.

[image]